# How to get a random number from min to max inclusive

Tags: rust

```
use rand::Rng;
fn main() {
    let mut zz = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut a: [i32; 4096] = [0; 4096];
    for n in 0..4096 {
        a[n] = zz.gen_range(-2147483648,2147483647);
    }
    ......
}
```

`gen_range(a,b)` can get a random number from `a` to `b`, but not included `b`.
If I write `gen_range(-2147483648,2147483648)`, it can't work, because `gen_range -> (i32,i32)`

So, what should I do?

Comment: What the problem with [`gen()`](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/trait.Rng.html#method.gen) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You may use `Uniform::from(std::i32::MIN..=std::i32::MAX)` with **inclusive** range too, and this is faster if sampling from the same range repeatedly:

```
use rand::distributions::{Distribution, Uniform};
fn main() {
    let between = Uniform::from(std::i32::MIN..=std::i32::MAX);
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut a = [0_i32; 4096];
    for i in 0..4096 {
        a[i] = between.sample(&mut rng);
    }
    println!("{} {}", a.iter().min().unwrap(), a.iter().max().unwrap());
}
```

---

2. Use array fill: `rng.fill(&mut a);`

```
use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};
fn main() {
    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    let mut a = [0_i32; 4096];
    rng.fill(&mut a); // array fill
    println!("{} {}", a.iter().min().unwrap(), a.iter().max().unwrap());
}
```

---

3. Using `a[i] = rng.gen()`

```
use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};
fn main() {
    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    let mut a = [0_i32; 4096];
    for i in 0..4096 {
        a[i] = rng.gen();
    }
    println!("{} {}", a.iter().min().unwrap(), a.iter().max().unwrap());
}
```

---

4. Array construction (len <=32):

```
let a: [i32; 32] = rng.gen();
```

---

5. Should you bound to use `gen_range`: since i32 range is -2147483648 to +2147483647 and  `gen_range` generate a random value in the range [low, high), i.e. inclusive of low and exclusive of high. One simple solution is:

```
a[i] = rng.gen_range(-2_147_483_648_i64, 2_147_483_648_i64) as i32;
```

Try:

```
use rand::Rng;
fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut a = [0_i32; 4096];
    for i in 0..4096 {
        a[i] = rng.gen_range(-2_147_483_648_i64, 2_147_483_648_i64) as i32;
    }
    println!("{} {}", a.iter().min().unwrap(), a.iter().max().unwrap());
}
```

This function is optimised for the case that only a **single sample** is made from the given range. See also the Uniform distribution type which may be faster if sampling from the same range repeatedly.

---